# Problem with $.get while submitting form

Tags: jquery, get, validation

I'm trying to verify that an Account Name is not already in use once a user fills out a form. The code looks like:

```
    $("#add_account").submit( function () { 
            $.get(
                "'.url::site("ajax/check_account_name").'", 
            {account_name: "t"}, 
            function(data){ 
                alert( data ); 
            }); 
        });
```

I get a $.get response if the statement sits like this:

```
    $(document).ready( function () { 
            $.get(
                "'.url::site("ajax/check_account_name").'", 
            {account_name: "t"}, 
            function(data){ 
                alert( data ); 
            }); 
        });
```

Which leads me to believe that my $.get statement is correct. Is there some jQuery rule I'm not familiar with that would cause this to fail in on submit scenario?

In code block 1, I get values returned like they should. Block 2 gives me a blank response.

Any ideas? Thanks for your time, I know you have better things to be doing.

Comment: As J-P said, `return false` at the end of your submit handler. @J-P, you should post that as an answer :)

Comment: what happens with the 1st block? Try 

.submit(function(e) { 
  e.preventDefault();
  // rest of your code
});

Comment: @J-P perfect. That fixed it. Why does it need return false; though? I've only been in Javascript/jQuery for about a month...I'm a PHP dev at heart. Just trying to learn the ropes.

Comment: I'm still having a problem... Basically I have an if-else handeling the returned $get data. I need the if to return false and the else to return true. However, it won't work unless I return false the entire .submit(). Any ideas how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript handlers fire before the default action of whatever it is you clicked on. So, if you have this $.get statement attached to the submit button of a form, then the $.get statement will fire before submitting the form via the browser methods.

To cancel this action, you should include `return false;` at the end of your click handler to cancel the default action, as J-P indicated. This works for links as well.

Comment: Thanks to you and J-P. 
I appreciate the explanation. It makes sense.